# Why is the compiler giving me an unreachable statement?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, while-loop

My goal is to make an String array which I'm going to send to a different method, it has to be a string array. Since I don't know how many strings are going to be entered I can't predict how many string are going to be used, I am using a arrayList. But when I try to convert the arrayList to a simple array, I got an unreachable statement error in my compiler.

I got the error here:

```
 String[] gradic = new String[lista.size()];
```

This is the rest of my code:

```
public static main(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter strings (empty line to end):");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (true){

        String x = in.nextLine();

        if (x.equals(" ")) continue;

        lista.add(x);
    }

    String[] x0 = new String[list.size()];
    lista.toArray(x0);

}
```

I want the arrayList to turn into a String[] array.

Comment: `while(true)` never exits. You wrote an infinite loop. Make that a real check based on the user's input where you check "what they wrote" in the while conditional, instead of doing a while true/break (you have `continue` at the moment. That just skips to a next iteration)

Comment: You probably want `break` instead of `continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop does not have any `break`, so the program cannot go out of it:

```
while (true){

    String x = in.nextLine();

    if (x.equals(" ")) continue;

    lista.add(x);
}
```

Probably you meant to write:

```
while (true){
    String x = in.nextLine();
    if (x.equals(" ")) break;
    lista.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting with Java programming, do not use `while(true)`, not even with an appropriate break. If you want to stop reading input when the user types something specific, *test for that* :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter strings (empty line to end):");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String input = "";

while (!input.equals(" ")) { // If this is your break condition: test for it.
    input = in.nextLine();
    if (!input.equals(" ")) {
      list.add(input);
    }
}
```

Does that check `input` twice? Yes. Is it "inefficient"? Not something you should care about, or can even meaningfully comment about in this kind of code. Is it explicit on what this code *should* do, to human readers? Very much so, and that's what matters for code you will be writing for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `while(true)` with code **after** the loop without a `break;` In general, given `while([condition])` if condition evaluates to **true** during compile time (such as with constants) then the while loop must have a break statement of some sort if there is code after the while. If there is no code after the while, it will be fine.